# When to use google Gson's tojson method which accepts type as a parameter? public String toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc)

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to convert my object into a JSON String using Gson's toJson API.
When I came across 2 different API's which supports the same.

> As per Docs -
>
> > **public String toJson(Object src)**
> >
> > > Note that this method works fine if the any of the object fields are of generic type, just the object itself should not be of a generic type.
> > >       **If the object is of generic type, use toJson(Object, Type) instead**.
> >
> > **public String toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc)**
> >
> > > This method must be used if the specified object is a generic type.

I'm using the 1st API which only takes Object as parameter however passing a generic type object and I'm still able to successfully get the JSON string.

Code:

```
@GET
@Path("/getList")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
public String getList()     
{       
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Message("kishore", " Bandi "));
    list.add(new Message("test", " values "));
    return gson.toJson(list);   
}
```

The XML I got as response:

```
[
    {
        "name": "kishore",
        "text": " Bandi ",
        "dontSend": "Hope not received",
        "iAmEmpty": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "test",
        "text": " values ",
        "dontSend": "Hope not received",
        "iAmEmpty": ""
    }
]
```

Same is the response even when I used Parameterized type.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Kishore");
        list.add("Bandi");
        return gson.toJson(list);
```

Output:

```
["Kishore","Bandi"]
```

So what's the significance of the second API which take type as parameter?

Answer (score 4):

The method `toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc)` is used when you are serializing/deserializing a `ParameterizedType`.

As per [docs](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html):

> If the object that your are serializing/deserializing is a
>   ParameterizedType (i.e. contains at least one type parameter and may
>   be an array) then you must use the toJson(Object, Type) or
>   fromJson(String, Type) method.

Example (extracted from docs):

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();
target.add("blah");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

Question related to `ParameterizedType`: [What is meant by parameterized type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551674/what-is-meant-by-parameterized-type)

Comment: In my example, I was using Parameterized type and I'm still able to get the json without having the specify the TokenType.
                
`    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`
`    list.add("Kishore");`
`    list.add("Bandi");`
`    return gson.toJson(list);`

Output:

    ["Kishore","Bandi"]

So the original API still works even for Parameterized type.