# TypeToken usage mandatory?

Tags: java, json, gson

Is is mandatory to use `TypeToken` (as recommended in the [Gson](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Type-) doc) as type when converting a list into json like below -

```
new Gson().toJson(dateRange, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());
```

For me below code is also working -

```
new Gson().toJson(dateRange, List.class);
```

Just want to make sure that code doesn't break.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use google Gson's tojson method which accepts type as a parameter? public String toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601355/when-to-use-google-gsons-tojson-method-which-accepts-type-as-a-parameter-publi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per docs -

> If the object that your are serializing/deserializing is a
>   `ParameterizedType` (i.e. contains at least one type parameter and may
>   be an array) then you must use the `toJson(Object, Type)` or
>   `fromJson(String, Type)` method. Here is an example for serializing and
>   deserializing a `ParameterizedType`:

```
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
 List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();
 target.add("blah");

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
 List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

This is the special case, in other cases you can use class type directly.
For reference - http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Hope this helps